# Exclude file type from fulltext index

Tags: sql, full-text-indexing

I have a fulltext index created on a varbinary(max) filestream column. I have both PDF's and XML's being stored in this filestream, and consequently both are being indexed. However, I really don't want to index the XML files, because I'm afraid that over time they'll bloat my index and slow it down. So what I would really like to do is only have my fulltext index on the PDF files instead. Is there a way to do this? Can I somehow disable the XML filter, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're able to distinguish between the two types of rows by a regular WHERE predicate (e.g. WHERE type = 'pdf') then you could create an indexed view that filters the rows to only those you want indexed and then full-text index the indexed view instead of the table. However, you'll need to query the view instead of the table to utilise the FTI.

Comment: Interesting idea. Any idea what the drawbacks might be by searching upon an indexed view? Slower perhaps?

Comment: An indexed view is just like a table, it has its own clustered index which means all the data is copied from the table into the (materialized) view. You can add indexes to it and really use it just like a regular table. However there are some restrictions, mostly on the nature of the SQL that defines the view. You'll also need to specify the `WITH (NOEXPAND)` query hint if you're not using Enterprise Edition in all queries you want to use an index of the view (although this doesn't apply to full text indexes).

Comment: The main drawback is that it will duplicate the BLOB. This will basically double the size of your documents in the database.